# Change url's in analytics reports

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I got this kind of URL in my site: /preinscripcion/231, the number is the code of a course and it is self generated by my CRM, the problem comes when I want to see to which course the person is trying to register, I have an excel with this codes but it is too demanding and cumbersome as I already have  hundreds of courses, I've tried with advanced filters to change my code with the name of the course, but I can only make up to 100 filters.

¿Is there a way of doing it?

It does not have to be on analytics itself, my site is made under wordpress http://formarte.edu.co/

Thanks in advance for all of your help.